# can ReleaseSemaphore() ever block?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have a multithreaded application running on WIN32 which uses a semaphore to protect a linked-list.  Very occasionally this locks-up.  When it locks-up I can stop the application in `cppvsdbg` under Visual Studio Code and I can see that two of the threads are waiting on the semaphore, i.e. they are blocked at:

`WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);`

However, the third thread is blocked here:

`ReleaseSemaphore(handle, 1, NULL);`

...i.e. it seems to have blocked on `ReleaseSemaphore()`, the very function which of course would allow one of the other two threads to run.  If I single step in the debugger, or I set a break-point just beyond the `ReleaseSemaphore()` call and continue running, nothing budges, the application remains locked up. The thread that is blocked at `ReleaseSemaphore()` is running at priority 0, the other two threads at priorities 0 and -1, so I can't see how thread priority could cause an issue.

More than that, I don't understand why `ReleaseSemaphore()` would block under any circumstances.  The value of `handle` is 0x000000ec, which is what it was at the start of the day, so the value of `handle` hasn't been corrupted, though I guess it is possible that the *contents* of `handle` might have been messed up somehow...?  Not sure how I would debug that.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why `ReleaseSemaphore()` might lock, or what additional things I might poke at in the debugger when the problem occurs to determine what's up?

EDIT: the code is compiled with `/Od` to avoid any misalignment between the visual debug and the code, this is a screen-shot of what the `cppvsdbg` window shows for the thread which appears to be blocked on `ReleaseSemaphore()`:

[image]

Comment: no, `ReleaseSemaphore` never blocked/wait. also *uses a semaphore to protect a linked-list* ? this is wrong object for *protect*

Comment: Ref. "This is a wrong object for _protect_". the code in question runs on multiple platforms, some of which do not support recursive mutexes.  Since a mutex on WIN32 is always recursive, on WIN32 we need to use a semaphore with a maximum count of 1 instead of a mutex for our protection.  But this is beside the point of course, the question is why the debugger shows that a thread is stopped at `ReleaseSemaphore()` when this lock-up occurs.

Comment: Something is wrong with the debugger? Try visual studio.

Comment: *the debugger shows that a thread is stopped at ReleaseSemaphore() when this lock-up occurs* i doubt in this

Comment: Maybe, but that is what the debugger shows, I have edited the original post to include a screenshot.

Comment: Why is there a `(HANDLE)` cast in the `ReleaseSemaphore` call? Can we be sure that your code is actually correct? Correct code doesn't need the cast.

Comment: As indicated, this is because the code runs on multiple platforms and hence we must use an abstraction `uPortMutexHandle_t` in the body of the code which maps to `void *` so it takes up 4 bytes, which works for all of our supported platforms (on Windows we use only 32 bit; Windows is really only for debugging, all the "real" platforms are RTOSes).  The porting layer for each platform then casts `uPortMutexHandle_t` to the specific type for that platform, which in the Windows case is `HANDLE`.

Comment: again - ReleaseSemaphore never blocked/wait. and not sure what your debugger actual show

Comment: @RbMm understood, I suppose that answers the question!  Something else must be going on, maybe somehow the contents of the handle has become corrupted.  I will look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: even if contents of the handle has become corrupted - you must not block - can error returned. i doubt that thread actually hang in this call. are you can step in by code in debugger ?

Comment: @RbMm: when I attempt to step in the debugger, either step-into or step-over, the executable begins to run again and does not stop (unless I pause the debugger again) because everything is in an OS call and I do not have source for `ntdll.dll`, which is where it _actually_ is.

Comment: @RbMM: S'OK, I think I've understood what's going on now, will post an answer once I've confirmed.

Comment: not need have source for ntdll.dll, but if you can set by asm code - you not hang

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find such an option in `cppvsdbg` under Visual Studio Code; maybe @MichaelChourdakis was right and I should try Visual Studio proper.

Comment: @Rob "*the code in question runs on multiple platforms, some of which do not support recursive mutexes. Since a mutex on WIN32 is always recursive, on WIN32 we need to use a semaphore with a maximum count of 1 instead of a mutex for our protection.*" - alternatively, have a look at [SRW locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks), which are not recursive.

Comment: @RemyLebeau very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the correct answer is: no, the Win32 API function `ReleaseSemaphore()` can never block.

The reason it *appeared* to be blocking in this case was because, separately, we needed to simulate critical sections on Windows (recalling that this code usually runs in an embedded system on an RTOS, Windows is only for rapid development).  To simulate a critical section on Windows we call `SuspendThread()` (and later `ResumeThread()`) on all threads except the current thread.  A failure was occurring *elsewhere* in the code while such a simulated critical section was in place, and it so happened that this coincided with the `ReleaseSemaphore()` call most of the time, making it look as though `ReleaseSemaphore()` had blocked; it hadn't, the thread just happened to get suspended there.

So we just had to fix the other bug and this apparent problem went away.